# Activate clock only when command block output is true

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to activate a clock when a player looks south. I got the command for it, but when I try to make a comparator clock even if I'm not looking south the comparator clock is still going, so how do I make a clock that will only activate when the command block output is true. I'm using a comparator to test if it is true, then a repeater to extend to 16 redstone then with that 16 redstone I use it to activate a comparator clock but when I'm not looking south the very 1st comparator doesn't turn off.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

[image]

Where the command block contains your command (and will also need to be being activated by a clock or something).

If that does not work, there is likely something wrong with your command, and you'll need to tell us it.

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked while the other comparator clocks I tried making didn't work. Thanks for the help

Comment: This works, but it isn't what you really want, because [redstone dust is evil](http://lemoesh.com/best-practices/eliminate-redstone-dust/)

Answer (score 3):

In 1.9, this can very easily (and less laggily) be done with conditional command blocks. If you want to activate a number of command blocks based on one condition, you should use a setup like this:

[image: Conditional repeating command block]

The first (impulse, orange) command block contains the condition, and should be activated whenever you want to check if the player is facing south (can be a repeating command block if you want to constantly check).

The next (repeating, indigo) command block is set to `Conditional`, which means that it will only activate, and thus only activate the chain command blocks that it's pointing into, when the condition in the block behind it is met. This and the chain command blocks should contain the actual commands you want to activate when the condition is met.